# Variable input detection

Tags: c#, checkbox, input, windows-forms-designer, detection

I am making a very repetitive form with a lot of check boxes that all interact with their relative textbox and was wondering if there was any way to have variable input detection such as,

```
Checkbox{X}.checkedchanged
Textbox{X}.text = "Example";
```

Comment: It is a vague description but maybe you want to look into UserControls (?????)

Comment: I think a `CustomControl` is what you're looking for (there is a difference between UserControl and CustomControl)